# Importance of threads in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

What is the importance of threads in the hadoop, while uploading the file from the local file system to the HDFS by the -put command?
Give an example if possible for better understanding of this application.

Whenever we upload the file in the HDFS through -put command, then the default thread size is 1, what will happen if we increase the thread size.

Comment: I'm not aware of any threading arguments to the put command. Why would you need more than one, though? Then the file may be written out of order